# Repo.all fails because I have a custom primary key

Tags: elixir, ecto

I generated and ran a migration for a table with no `id` field (uses the field `league_id` as a primary key). I confirmed that the migration worked as intended (checked the database in psql and the table indeed has no `id` field and `league_id` is the primary key).

When I run `Repo.all(League)` I get the following error:

`13:01:14.962 [debug] QUERY ERROR source="leagues" db=2.8ms`

`SELECT l0."id", l0."league_id" FROM "leagues" AS l0 []`

`** (Postgrex.Error) ERROR 42703 (undefined_column): column l0.id does not exist`

Is there a way to tell `Repo.all/1` that there is no id field (aside from manually building a `SELECT *` -type query?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use a different primary key column than `id`, you can specify that using the `@primary_key` attribute when declaring the schema:

```
# See documentation link below for what values the options list accepts.
@primary_key {:league_id, :id, []} 
schema "leagues" do
  ...
end
```

or if you don't want to use that column in queries, you can set the key to `false`:

```
@primary_key false
schema "leagues" do
  ...
end
```

[The documentation](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Schema.html#module-schema-attributes) explains this in detail.

Comment: Thanks! For future readers just note I had to add an empty list to the tuple to avoid a compile error (it expects `false` or `{ name, type, opts }`, and that when you define the primary key in this way you don't also include that field in the `schema` call.

Comment: Thanks, I've fixed the answer to include the options list!

Answer (score 0):

FYI: I additionally have to override the field in the schema block when there is a many_to_many relationship.

```
@primary_key {:personid, :id, autogenerate: true}

schema "people" do
    field :id, :integer, [source: :personid]
    ...
    many_to_many :...
end
```